# Add two time values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two fields - transaction time in UTC and the UTC offset. The transaction time has HH:MI format, while the offset has +/- HH:MI format. How can I add these two values in Oracle 11g?

Comment: What datatypes are each field?

Comment: Both are VARCHAR

Comment: VARCHAR for a timestamp, oh boy. So no date component to the transaction time anywhere?

Comment: We have the transaction date (DD/MM/YYYY) in a separate field.

Comment: Only the people who do not understand the ways in which `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` work in database insist on storing them as `VARCHAR` . They believe that somehow it is "readily available"  to you to see the values in desired format and manipulate as needed. What they don't realize is the fact that it is much harder to convert such `VARCHAR` columns back to DATE to do the necessary processing such as ordering,difference,addition etc, which is often the case with dates. So, i recommend you to propose this to your supervisor/stake holders/db designers to change the column to `TIMESTAMP` ASAP.

Comment: [We should not use `VARCHAR` anyway](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm). The standard string type in Oracle is `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I think (at least I hope) this is just a lazy typo but the real data type is actually `VARCHAR2`

Comment: Yes, it is actually VARCHAR2 and not VARCHAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a really bad design to store date/times in the way you are doing it. Converting it to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` will make your life much easier.

You can make the conversion like this:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
    date_column ||' '|| time_column ||' '|| UTC_offset_column, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZH:TZM')
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise that you not store dates and times as varchar. It complicates not only this query but makes sorting, grouping, indexing, and querying much slower. Regardless, you need to convert the date and time column into a date datetype, then parse the offset column and turn that into an interval you can use for date math.

```
SELECT to_date(date_column || ' ' || time_column, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI') + 
       TO_DSINTERVAL(decode(substr(offset_column,1,1),'-', '-') || '0 0' || substr(offset_column, 3) || ':00') AS calculated_time
  FROM your_table
```